# GET data from html forms

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms

```
def scan(request):
    scan = Stock.objects.all()
    type = 'Hammer'
    filter = {}
    if request.GET.get('filter'):
        type = request.GET['filter']
    filter[type] = 100
    hammer = Stock.objects.filter(**filter)
    belthold = Stock.objects.filter(Belthold=100)

    context = {'All': scan, 'Belthold': belthold, 'Hammer': hammer
```

This is my views.py file and the following is html for a dropdown menu I am making:

```
<form method="get">
         <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <label for="filter">Filter</label>
            <select name="filter" id="filter">
                <option value="Hammer">Hammer</option>
                <option value="Belthold">Belthold</option>
            </select>
         </select>
</form>
```

Oddly enough, i get this on my html page:
[image]

Any idea where things could have gone wrong?

Additional info:
[image]

This is the database, for each stock if a pattern is formed (i.e. Hammer, Belthold) the data represent 100 and 0 for no.

[image]

this is the html page. Note that I have only rendered out basic stock data from the database (First 7 columns). And the current view shows stocks that hv formed 'hammer' pattern. If i need to change to a different pattern say belt hold, i will hv to do it manually. So, I want a dropdown above the html page that changes the filter in the backend and only relevant stocks are rendered.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do as I can't understand what the .filter() at hammer and belthold are supposed to return in views.py, but I noticed that in the dropdown you are not using your context that you defined in views. It should be, for example: <option value="{{ Hammer }}">{{ Hammer }}</option>

Comment: the filter will look into the database (see pic # 2) and check which object/stock/script has hammer = 100 or belthold = 100. Then display those object/stock/script to the html page (see pic # 3, it shows all the scripts have Hammer=100 in the database). Hope i make sense. P.S. the alteration u suggested with the html page doesn't work. THANKSS

Comment: Sorry, it still does not make sense to me. On views.py you are filtering for a type field that have a value of 100 in your Stock class, but there are no field with name type in your models (pic # 2). The same goes for filtering a field Belthold with value 100. Only your scan variable would return something. Try your template with scan and see if something shows up.

Comment: my bad, the pic doesn't show hammer or belthold due to the space constraint, but they are actually there.